# Exeception areas for stopPropagation in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having a tabs in my content, I'm trying to display a button once the tabs div area is being clicked, now I'm using `stopPropagation` to execute it, while using it I came to know that if I use the `stopPropagation` tabs doesn't work but while removing it tabs are working fine but the buttons are not being displayed. Is there any way out where I can have both the functionality working, I tried putting the `stopPropagation` in the tab contents and left the `<ul>` area, buttons doesn't display. Can you help me out with this following is my code:

```
$('#nitstabs').click(function (e) { // setting execption areas for closing popup
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Following is [the link](http://www.noeticitservices.com/nitsdemo/NitsEditor/edit/editor.php) you can find it in `why with us?` tab

Comment: how are you adding the buttons? Can you show that?

Comment: Please check the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2175r6we/) link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **editor.js**

Problem is you are adding the click even
t to this element `$('#nitstabs')` this is the `div` that wraps up all your tabs and stuff.. So obviously the click on any tab, etc will result in this parent `div` click and hence you tabs are not opening.. What you need is **except the ul tabs add the click event to all other elements**

So use this selector

`$('#nitstabs > *:not(ul.nav.nav-tabs)')` instead of `$('#nitstabs')`

Comment: And what about `stopPropagation` shall I leave it as it is?

Comment: @NitishKumar Glad I could help you. :)